# Removing the parentheses from the values of the dictionary when printing

Tags: python

I have the following function where I would like to generate a dictionary based on the number of parameters introduced:

```
def find_posit(*param):
    query = {'colors':param}
    return query

print(find_posit('red','blue','green'))
```

When printing the function, the returned output is something like this:

```
{'colors':('red','blue','green')}
```

How could I obtain the following output?

```
 {'colors': 'red','blue','green'}
```

Comment: `print(str(find_posit(red,blue,green)).replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))`

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't. That's just the way Python defines the `__repr__()` for tuple objects.

Comment: Imagine if there were multiple key-value pairs in the dictionary. The commas, while technically still unambiguous, would be a mess for the human reader. `{'colors': red, blue, green, 'data': 7, 8, 9, 'foo': bar}`

Comment: replace: `query = {'colors':param}` with: `query = {'colors': ",".join(param)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. That's just the way Python defines the `__repr__()`esentation for tuple objects.

However, you could create a custom function to "stringify" the dictionary in the representation that you want:

```
>>> def print_custom_dict(d):
    pairs = []
    for k, v in d.items():
            pair = '{}: {}'.format(repr(k), ','.join(repr(val) for val in v))
            pairs.append(pair)
    return '{%s}' % ', '.join(pairs)

>>> print_custom_dict({'colors':('red', 'blue', 'green')})
"{'colors': 'red','blue','green'}"
```

Of course, there are others options you could take such as defining a custom `tuple`-ish object, and modifying the `__repr__()` of it to print the desired output, but in your case using a simple helper function IMO is the simplest and cleanest method.

Comment: +1 for the custom tuple-ish object. That's definitely the solution that will scale better for non-trivial use cases.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yup, your right. While I think a function is the cleaner solution for a trivial case such as this, a custom object would be much better, cleaner, and more robust for the non-trivial use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but according to python documentation without using any datatypes you can't  add multiple value to dictionary, so you can not remove tuples.may i am wrong .here is your code.

```html
def find_posit(*param):
    query = {'colors':param}
    return query

print(find_posit('red','blue','green'))
```